# Wordpress Cron Job calling class function doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

> I am using Wordpress Cron Job to call static function of a class.
>
> The cron event is triggered but the function isn't called.
>
> Can you help me to fix it?

Here is my functions.php file.

```
...    
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'calculate_score' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'calculate_score');
}

add_action('calculate_score', 'calculate_score');
function calculate_score()
{   
    require_once ASIATHEMES_TEMPLATE_DIR."/../../../wp-load.php";
    require_once ASIATHEMES_TEMPLATE_DIR.'/../../../wp-content/plugins/football-pool/admin/class-football-pool-admin.php';
    require_once ASIATHEMES_TEMPLATE_DIR.'/../../../wp-content/plugins/football-pool/admin/class-football-pool-admin-score-calculation.php';

    Football_Pool_Admin_Score_Calculation::process();
}
...
```

> process() is a static function of
>   Football_Pool_Admin_Score_Calculation Class.

Here is the file.

```
<?php
class Football_Pool_Admin_Score_Calculation extends Football_Pool_Admin {
    public static function process() {
        // session data is initiated in Football_Pool->init

        // initialize variables
        global $wpdb;
    ...
    }
```

> This function can be called from other php file, but not in cron job.

Comment: what do you mean by "it cannot be called" is there an error or or doesn't it do anything?

Comment: It cannot be called.

Comment: well, this does not answer my question ;)

never registered a cronjob in WP but, from  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event
it says: use the activation hook for that - but that is more or less unrelated to "it cannot be called" (... because there is an Exception at line X saying ....)

Comment: Of course, the function calculate_score() in functions.php is called by cron job, but it cannot call the function process() of class Football_Pool_Admin_Score_Calculation.

Comment: Ever figure this out?